# Getting Error in Queries in COGNOS 10.2

Tags: cognos-10

I am new to Development in COGNOS 10.2. I am trying to create a logic:

```
IF(ParamCount('ord')=1) THEN ('SI')ELSE('NULL')
IF(ParamCount('ord')>1) THEN ('MI')ELSE('NULL')
IF(ParamCount('ord')< ) THEN('NULL')
```

The first one give no error how ever the last two gives error. Please suggest.
Niha

Comment: The comparison in the last conditional is lacking a second parameter (I assume it should be 1)

Answer (score 0):

Use search case. Following is how it should be. Also if you are trying to return null, it should not be in quotes.

```
CASE 
WHEN ParamCount('ord') = 1 THEN 'SI'
WHEN ParamCount('ord') > 1 THEN 'MI'
WHEN ParamCount('ord') < 1 THEN null
ELSE null
END
```